# sed script for modifying the start and end of a para in even/odd fashion

Tags: sed

I wish to use sed to modify the starting and ending pattern of a code with odd/even occurrences in  block/para, for e.g.

> ```
> Word1
> .....
> Word1
>
> Word1
> .....
> Word1
> ```

with replacing "word1" in the beginning with "NewWord1"(odd times, 1,3,5,7,..) and replacing "word1" in the end with "NewWord2"(even times, 2,4,6,...)

> ```
> NewWord1
> .....
> NewWord2
>
> NewWord1
> .....
> NewWord2
> ```

Comment: `[...]` brackets in regular expressions don't work on words like that - they work on sets of characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are working with paragraphs, then Awk or Perl are probably simpler

Ex. with GNU Awk:

```
$ gawk -vRS= '
    BEGIN{OFS=FS="\n"} 
    {sub(/Word1/,"NewWord1",$1); sub(/Word1/,"NewWord2",$NF)}
    {printf $0 RT}
' SampleCode
NewWord1
.....
NewWord2

NewWord1
.....
NewWord2
```

Comment: I have tried using 

    sed -i -E ':a;N;$!ba;  s/Word1([^Word1]+[Word1|$])/NewWord1\1/g' SampleCode
    sed -i -E ':a;N;$!ba;  s/Word1([^Word1])/NewWord2\1/g' SampleCode

And it works like a charm

Taken help from 
[comamnd for odd occurence][1]


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54239046/how-to-use-sed-or-awk-or-something-similar-to-replace-every-odd-occurrence-of-ch

Comment: @pasmon it may appear to "work like a charm" but for example `[^Word1]+` is matching a non-empty sequence of any characters excluding `W`,`o`,`r`,`d` and `1` - that is **not** the same as matching any *string* that is not equal to `Word1`

Comment: Can you give an example?